# Has anyone used the Atiyah-Singer Index Theorem in number theory?

Tags: number-theory, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, representation-theory

The Atiyah-Singer Index theorem is one of the most influential theorems in geometry/PDE/topology. It generalizes many previous theorems in geometry such as $V - E + F = 2$, Gauss-Bonet theorem, Riemann-Roch theorem, etc.

Part of Tate's thesis was to prove the Riemann-Roch theorem for curves over finite fields, this was done through the use of the Poisson summation formula in harmonic analysis. It is my understanding that the Poisson summation formula has also a lot of depth and has been generalized in the form of the Selberg trace formula.

My question is if these two "families" of theorems meet again. Perhaps more specifically, has there been a significant use of the Atiyah-Singer Index theorem in problems of number theory or representation theory?